# Template does not exist from the main app

Tags: django

I have a project that looks like this

```
main
--templates
----main
------contact.html
--settings.py
app1
app2
app3
app4
```

Each of my other apps templates work correctly. But now I am trying to reference a template in my `main` app but I get the error `Template does not exist`

Since this is my main app (base app?) it doesn't  have a `apps.py` and it isn't added to the `INSTALLED_APPS`. I altered my settings.py file to look like this..

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT), 'main/templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
```

This works on my Windows dev station but when I push it to my live Ubuntu server is when I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Found out I had to update my TEMPLATES to..

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT), BASE_DIR + '/main/templates'],
```